# Qt Android : How to properly manage media playing in background

Tags: android, qt, media-player, qml

I'm developing a webradio app in `qml` with `Qt 5.2`. To play my radio stream I use a `MediaPlayer` qml element. This method allows to keep music playing when the user goes in other application, that's what I want. However when the user play an other media my radio stream doesn't stop and so there is two media playing in the same time.

I have checked with other media player app, this behavior is not normal in android. Normally the first media should automatically be paused when a second one starts playing.

Does anyone know how to reproduce this behavior with in `Qt` ?